# provide leaflet-map to react-component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, leaflet

I'm using react-leaflet to render a map. I created a component that has a map-property:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Map, FeatureCollection } from  'leaflet';

class Car extends React.Component {
    
    state = { 
        map: Map,
        collection: FeatureCollection
    }
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            map: props.map,
            collection: props.collection
        }
    }
```

Now I try to use that component within my app:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { MapContainer, useMap } from 'react-leaflet';
import Car from './Car';

function Layout() {

    return (
        <div>
            <MapContainer bounds={[[52.475,13.3], [52.477,13.5]]} zoom={12}>
                <Car map={ useMap() }/>
            </MapContainer> 
        </div>
    )
}

export default Layout;
```

However I don't know how to provide the map from the `MapContainer` into my `Car`-component. Using the above code I get the following error:

> TS2322: Type '{ map: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
> Property 'map' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.

Comment: `export type CarProps = {map: Map, collection: FeatureCollection}` and then `export default class Car extends React.Component<CarProps, CarProps> {`

Answer (score 0):

`useMap` can only be used within a component that is itself a child/descendant of `<MapContainer>`.
https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map/#usemap

> Hook providing the Leaflet Map instance in any descendant of a `MapContainer`.

Your `<Layout>` component *renders* such `<MapContainer>`, but is not *within* one.

However, you can simply use `useMap` in the body of `<Car>`

That being said, it will probably not work if you keep your `<Car>` component class-based. You will probably have to either convert it to functional component, or use an older version of React Leaflet (2).

Comment: That worked, however I don't like my `Car`-component to get the map itself. I'd rather inject the map from the outside, so that `Car` does not even need to be within a `MapContainer`, but instead just gets a map from somewhere.